# Lemmermeyer's proof of Kronecker-Weber

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, kummer-theory

I am reading Lemmermeyer's proof of Kronecker-Weber, specifically the proof of Proposition 1.1. The paper is linked here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1108.5671.pdf 

The setup is as follows: $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is a cyclic extension of degree $p$, $F=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p})$, and $L=KF$ is the compositum. Now, $L/F$ is a cyclic extension, so we can write it in the form $F(\mu^{1/p})$. Following the proof of Lemma 2.1, he concludes that $(1-\zeta)$ cannot divide $\mu$. I am unable to see why this is true. Similarly, in the next line, he again says that if $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal not dividing $p$, then $\mathfrak{p}^{bp}||\mu$ for some integer $b$. I cannot see why this its true either, because the previous proposition does not imply that this happens for primes of the form which are $1 \pmod{p}$, as these split completely. If I could get a hint on how to proceed with respect to these doubts, I would be thankful.


Edit: I have figured out why the second point holds. This can be seen by the fact that $L/F$ is unramified outside $p$, and by looking at the prime factorization of $(\mu^{1/p})$ in $O_{L}$. However, I am still dumbfounded as to why the first point holds.

Comment: If $1-\zeta$ divides $\mu$, then $p$ must ramify completely. Delete the "in particular". While I am at it, I should have referred to David Speyer's blog article https://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2008/05/05/the-cubic-kronecker-weber-theorem/ . In addition I am pretty certain that the proof I have given is essentially one of those given by Weber, the one where he uses e.g. that the class group of the fields of $2^n$-th roots of unity is odd; but reading Weber's proof isn't easy.

Comment: $p$ does ramify completely in all extensions though right? It obviously ramifies completely in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p})$, and since it ramifies in $K$, it has to ramify completely (prime degree). The degrees are coprime, so it ramifies in the composite as well.

Comment: Forget what I said. Apply the proposition with ${\mathfrak q} = (1-\zeta)$.

Comment: Applying that, I am only able to conclude that in $\mu$, $\mathfrak{q}$ has an exponent divisible by $p$. I still don't see it.

Comment: You are allowed to  cancel $p$-th roots of elements without changing the extension since $F(\sqrt[p]{\xi^p \mu} )= F(\sqrt[p]{\mu})$.

Comment: That is fine, but that statement is in terms of ideals. i.e. $(\mu)=(1-\zeta_{p})^{bp} \mathfrak{a}$. From this, we can just say $\mu=\sum_{i} ((1-\zeta_{p})^{bp}b_{i})(a_{i})$, for $a_{i} \in \mathfrak{a},b_{i} \in \mathfrak{O}_{F}$, and , which does allow us to cancel out the $(1-\zeta_{p})^{bp}$. But there is also the possibility of all $b_{i}$'s being divisible by $(1-\zeta_{p})$, creating a problem.

Comment: Now you lost me - I can't see where the sum is coming from. Both $\mu$ and $1-\zeta_p$ are principal

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147460/discussion-between-dormordo-and-franz-lemmermeyer).